# Filling up remaining space in svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I tried to create an svg and adding path to it.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adityasingh773/ppxzfpLa/)

Now, as you can see, I managed to create a down facing triangle but what I am not able to do is filling up the rest of the space(white colored) inside the svg with some other color(say black). How do I do that?

Here is my **HTML**

```
<svg id="bigTriangleColors" width="100%" height="100" 
viewBox="0 0 100 102" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

and **CSS**

```
#bigTriangleColors {
fill: #E1EAEF;
position: relative;
}
svg:not(:root) {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If I understood correctly, but have you just tried to set the background color on svg

```
svg {
    bacground-color: black;
}
```

like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Luoq4Lcz/ ?

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, that will do! Is it ethical though?

Comment: be careful with setting the background-color to svg because all your svg get the background-color. use the id (`#bigTriangleColors`) instead!

Answer (score 0):

Using `background-color` on `<svg>` element works (I believe) in all the latest browser versions, but it didn't work on older versions of every browser.

If backwards compatibility is important to you, then a better solution would be to either:

- surround the SVG with a `<div>` and give that a background colour, or
- add a rectangle of the desired colour to the SVG itself:

```html
<svg id="bigTriangleColors" width="100%" height="100" 
viewBox="0 0 100 102" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
  <path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0 Z" fill="red"></path>
</svg>
```